# Create table from a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, create-table

Below is the query I tried to execute in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE List 
AS 
    (SELECT * FROM counts)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near '('

I did some research on google to understand and isolate the error, but, failed to do so. Could anyone please help me understand the error. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL-Server's syntax to create a table from a query is by adding an `into` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO   list
FROM   counts
```